# How to pass checked and unchecked checkbox value to another Activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my working code for passing checked and unchecked checkbox value to another Activity:

This is First Activity image.

[FIRST ACTIVITY Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooB2j.png)

This is Second Activity Image.

[SECOND ACTIVITY Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujRCf.png)

---

1.This is First Activity xml file.

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/activity_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context="com.example.himanshu.checkbox_module.FirstActivity">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="First Activity"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="#f00"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Monday"

                android:onClick="onCheckedBox"
                android:id="@+id/mon"/>
            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tuesday"
                android:onClick="onCheckedBox"
                android:id="@+id/tue"/>
            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Wednesday"
                android:onClick="onCheckedBox"
                android:id="@+id/wed"/>
            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Thursday"
                android:onClick="onCheckedBox"
                android:id="@+id/thu"/>
            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Friday"
                android:onClick="onCheckedBox"
                android:id="@+id/fri"/>
            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Saturday"
                android:onClick="onCheckedBox"
                android:id="@+id/sat"/>
            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sunday"
                android:onClick="onCheckedBox"
                android:id="@+id/sun"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="send to second activity"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/button1"/>


        </LinearLayout>
```

---

2.This is First Activity java file.

```
        package com.example.himanshu.checkbox_module;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.CheckBox;
    import android.widget.TextClock;

    public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        Intent intentData;
        Button buttonSend;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            intentData = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);

            buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

            buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    startActivity(intentData);

                }
            });
        }

        public void onCheckedBox(View view){

            boolean checked = ((CheckBox)view).isChecked();

            switch (view.getId()){

                case R.id.mon:if (checked){
                    intentData.putExtra("MON","Monday");
                }else {
                    intentData.removeExtra("MON");
                }break;

                case R.id.tue:if (checked){
                    intentData.putExtra("TUE","Tuesday");
                }else {
                    intentData.removeExtra("TUE");
                }break;

                case R.id.wed:if (checked){
                    intentData.putExtra("WED","Wednesday");
                }else {
                    intentData.removeExtra("WED");
                }break;

                case R.id.thu:if (checked){
                    intentData.putExtra("THU","Thursday");
                }else {
                    intentData.removeExtra("THU");
                }break;

                case R.id.fri:if (checked){
                    intentData.putExtra("FRI","Friday");
                }else {
                    intentData.removeExtra("FRI");
                }break;

                case R.id.sat:if (checked){
                    intentData.putExtra("SAT","Saturday");
                }else {
                    intentData.removeExtra("SAT");
                }break;

                case R.id.sun:if (checked){
                    intentData.putExtra("SUN","Sunday");
                }else {
                    intentData.removeExtra("SUN");
                }break;

                default:break;

            }
        }
    }
```

---

3.This is Second Activity xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_secon"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.himanshu.checkbox_module.SecondActivity">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Second Activity"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#f00"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textview_result"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

4.This is Second Activity java file.

```
package com.example.himanshu.checkbox_module;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView showResult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_secon);

        showResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_result);

        Intent intentResult = this.getIntent();

        String monday = intentResult.getStringExtra("MON");
        String tuesday = intentResult.getStringExtra("TUE");
        String wednesday = intentResult.getStringExtra("WED");
        String thursday = intentResult.getStringExtra("THU");
        String friday = intentResult.getStringExtra("FRI");
        String saturday = intentResult.getStringExtra("SAT");
        String sunday = intentResult.getStringExtra("SUN");

        showResult.setText(monday+" , "+tuesday+" , "+wednesday+" , "+thursday+" , "+friday+",  "+saturday+" , "+sunday);
    }
}
```

Comment: post your code what you have tried.

Comment: `i hope it will be helpful for you`. No. Not at all. You are not passing checkbox values (true/false) but a string value. So your code is not a solution for your question. Look at the answer of @Simon Andersson which shows how you do such things properly.

Answer (score 5):

```
boolean isChecked = myCheckBox.isChecked();

    Intent i = new Intent(this, secondActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("checkBoxValue", isChecked);
    startActivity(i);
```

In your second activity `onCreate`

```
boolean isChecked = this.getIntent().getBooleanExtra("checkBoxValue", false);
```